# Use Multi Categories in Joomla Component

Tags: joomla

in the attached image you see that i am create an categories for my component for this view.

this is good but my problem is that i need to another categories for another view.

access.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access component="com_afzonehnevis">
    <section name="component">
        <action name="core.admin" title="JACTION_ADMIN" description="JACTION_ADMIN_COMPONENT_DESC" />
        <action name="core.options" title="JACTION_OPTIONS" description="JACTION_OPTIONS_COMPONENT_DESC" />
        <action name="core.manage" title="JACTION_MANAGE" description="JACTION_MANAGE_COMPONENT_DESC" />
        <action name="core.create" title="JACTION_CREATE" description="JACTION_CREATE_COMPONENT_DESC" />
        <action name="core.delete" title="JACTION_DELETE" description="JACTION_DELETE_COMPONENT_DESC" />
        <action name="core.edit" title="JACTION_EDIT" description="JACTION_EDIT_COMPONENT_DESC" />
        <action name="core.edit.state" title="JACTION_EDITSTATE" description="JACTION_EDITSTATE_COMPONENT_DESC" />
        <action name="core.edit.own" title="JACTION_EDITOWN" description="JACTION_EDITOWN_COMPONENT_DESC" />
    </section>
    <section name="category">
        <action name="core.create" title="JACTION_CREATE" description="COM_CATEGORIES_ACCESS_CREATE_DESC" />
        <action name="core.delete" title="JACTION_DELETE" description="COM_CATEGORIES_ACCESS_DELETE_DESC" />
        <action name="core.edit" title="JACTION_EDIT" description="COM_CATEGORIES_ACCESS_EDIT_DESC" />
        <action name="core.edit.state" title="JACTION_EDITSTATE" description="COM_CATEGORIES_ACCESS_EDITSTATE_DESC" />
        <action name="core.edit.own" title="JACTION_EDITOWN" description="COM_CATEGORIES_ACCESS_EDITOWN_DESC" />
    </section>
</access>
```

how can i do it?

Attached image:

[this is a view that use com_categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXit4.png)

thank you for answer.

Comment: What do you mean by another category for another view? Are you unable to create any menu item?

Comment: hi, thank you for comment, i'm create "Product category" with joomla com_categories component,this is ok, but i need another category for "Subscription" view , in act i need "Subscription Category" , but joomla com_categories component provide just 1 category view by extension name, this is my problem. thanks

Comment: You can create multiple categories for your extension. I dont understand what you mean by category view. There is no restriction for extension that only one category can be built for one extension. Did you check this link https://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Adding_categories ?

Comment: this is my product categories view address : `/administrator/index.php?option=com_categories&extension=com_afzonehnevis`. As you see, the com_categories component provides category view once for each component by extension name. i nedd another categories. how can i do.

Comment: It is obvious that for each there can only be one category view. That is how it is made. Create as many categories to whatever level you want. Each category can be accessed through its id.